# Login using REST request gives 404

Tags: users, 8

This is so simple login request but cannot figure out why I am getting such error message when trying to login using Postman.

I use url `http://localhost:8080/user/login?_format=json` and input in the header `Content-Type:application/json` and I have in my body `{"name":"user", "pass":"pass"}` but I am getting this error message

> {     "message": "The \"user\" parameter was not converted for the path
>   \"/user/{user}\" (route name: \"rest.entity.user.GET\")" }

Using curl works though:

```
curl --header "Content-type: application/json" --request POST --data '{"name":"admin", "pass":"pass"}' http://localhost:8080/user/login?_format=json
```

curl result:

> {"current_user":{"uid":"1","roles":["authenticated","administrator"],"name":"admin"},"csrf_token":"XXXXX","logout_token":"XXXXX"}

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same issue and resolved it by selecting "POST" method from dropdown list.

Find the below image:-
[image]

**OUTPUT:-**
{
    "current_user": {
        "uid": "1",
        "roles": [
            "authenticated",
            "administrator"
        ],
        "name": "admin"
    },
    "csrf_token": "XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "logout_token": "XXXXXXXXXXX"
}

**Note:** we can get this output for the first time, if we try for the second time we will get message like

> {
>       "message": "This route can only be accessed by anonymous users." }

because postman works as a browser. 
To get it work for the second time we need to remove the cookie from postman.

Kindly let me know if I am wrong.
Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

This works for me (leave it on multiple lines):

```
$ curl --insecure \
  --header "Content-type: application/json" \
  --request POST "https://bo.mywebsite.com:8001/user/login?_format=json" \
  --data '{"name":"admin", "pass":"SuperSecret123&"}'
```

> Note: `--insecure` is used to skip SSL verification.